# yum transaction check error when installing mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, yum, centos5

I'm trying to install mysql 5.6 on our Centos 5 server, but no matter which instructions I follow, I keep ending up with a yum transaction error.

I've tried upgrading Mysql 5.1 to 5.6, and I've also tried simply removing mysql completely and doing a fresh install, but it just won't work.

For example if I run `yum remove mysql mysql-*`

It confirms that there are no mysql packages installed.

I downloaded the rpm for Linux 5 from the MySQL website.

I then do a `yum localinstall mysql-community-release-el5-5.noarch.rpm` but that says "does not update installed packages".

I've tried removing mysql-community-release-el5-5 and also the el6 which i accidently installed, but using `yum remove` they both say "no match for argument: PACKAGENAMEHERE"

So instead I try `rpm -Uvh mysql-community-release-el5-5.noarch.rpm` and it says it is already installed.

So I ran `rpm -e mysql-community-release` to remove it, then did the previous step again and it didn't say it was already installed, so presumably has now installed it again.

Then I run `yum install mysql-community-server` and this is where I get the transaction check error:

```
yum install mysql-community-server
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: centos.serverspace.co.uk
 * base: mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net
 * contrib: centos.serverspace.co.uk

 * epel: mirrors.coreix.net
 * extras: mirrors.coreix.net
 * rpmforge: mirror.nl.leaseweb.net
 * rpmforge-extras: mirror.nl.leaseweb.net
 * updates: centos.serverspace.co.uk
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-community-server.i386 0:5.6.25-2.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-common = 5.6.25-2.el5 for package: mysql-community-server
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-client = 5.6.25-2.el5 for package: mysql-community-server
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-community-client.i386 0:5.6.25-2.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-libs = 5.6.25-2.el5 for package: mysql-community-client
---> Package mysql-community-common.i386 0:5.6.25-2.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: mysql = 5.6.25-2.el5 for package: mysql-community-common
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql.i386 0:5.6.25-2.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-libs-compat = 5.6.25-2.el5 for package: mysql
---> Package mysql-community-libs.i386 0:5.6.25-2.el5 set to be updated
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-community-libs-compat.i386 0:5.6.25-2.el5 set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================================
 Package                           Arch       Version             Repository               Size
================================================================================================
Installing:
 mysql-community-server            i386       5.6.25-2.el5        mysql56-community        83 M
Installing for dependencies:
 mysql                             i386       5.6.25-2.el5        mysql56-community        38 k
 mysql-community-client            i386       5.6.25-2.el5        mysql56-community        22 M
 mysql-community-common            i386       5.6.25-2.el5        mysql56-community       692 k
 mysql-community-libs              i386       5.6.25-2.el5        mysql56-community       2.3 M
 mysql-community-libs-compat       i386       5.6.25-2.el5        mysql56-community       2.0 M

Transaction Summary
================================================================================================
Install       6 Package(s)
Upgrade       0 Package(s)

Total size: 110 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Finished Transaction Test


Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.15.0.0 from install of mysql-community-libs-compat-5.6.25-2.el5.i386 conflicts with file from package mysqlclient15-5.0.91-1.jason.1.i386
  file /usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.so.15.0.0 from install of mysql-community-libs-compat-5.6.25-2.el5.i386 conflicts with file from package mysqlclient15-5.0.91-1.jason.1.i386

Error Summary
```

I've even tried completely deleting the /usr/lib/mysql directory prior to doing this, but it still happens.

Could anyone help me resolve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to resolve this now, typically as soon as I'd asked the question.

Running `rpm -qa mysql\*` showed me this mysqlclient.jason thing, which I was able to remove with `rpm -e` and then it let me install